# Discord py write something in document

Tags: discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def ppadd(ctx, nums):
    with open("paypal.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            paypal = lines
        f.close()
    operation = f"{line} + {nums}"
    await ctx.send(f'{operation} = {eval(operation)}')
w = open("paypal.txt", 'w')

for line in lines:
    if paypal not in line:
        w.write(eval(operation))

w.close()
```

Hey, i wanna add a overview of my balance to my bot, the !balance command works, but i wanna have the command !ppadd to add a number of money i earned this day. Everything works as i want, but in the .txt document it doesnt replace the old amount with the new one, it just clears the document. Anybody knwo, hwo to help me?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a txt file? Why not a json or csv? Text files are a pain to work with imo

Comment: No, i could also use a json file im gonna change that. Maybe can you help how the code would be if i would use a json file?